# Is it possible to bridge more than one pixel in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have several lines in a binary image. I know the code `bridgeBW = bwmorph(closeBW, 'bridge');` will connect the lines if they are close enough, but so far I've only seen it do that in a one pixel range. Is there a way to increase the distance and bridge lines that are farther away?

Comment: `imdilate` with [line-based `strel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/strel-class.html)?

Comment: @Mia There is no single solution to this. A trivial solution would be to connect all edge pixels to each other, but that's probably not what you need. it might be easier if you gave an example image showing what you have in mind.

Comment: Sure, let me clarify it as well

Comment: There are a million ways to do this.  Hough transform, morphological dilation / closing, image inpainting. This question is too broad IMHO.

Comment: I've tried all of those except inpainting, but the gap is too wide and the lines are not straight

Comment: You can detect the two edges (will be the only pixels having only one neighbor) and then force a straight line to connect them.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki the edgepixel at the far left contradicts this assumption (it has 2 neighbours)

Comment: Get the contour indices for those two lines and look for the closest pair of indices and join them with a straight line?

Comment: @Mia thank you for the image, but I imagined as much. I was more after an image to answer, for instance, how would you envisage the "bridging" in this scenario? http://i.imgur.com/DuCJhOA.png

Comment: @Mia If you have implemented that I would encourage you to post an answer yourself. I have found out that people learn a lot from self-answered posts, so do consider doing that. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a line based `strel` method instead of one defined by a shape.